# Add elements to a custom class list

Tags: java

I have created a custom class:

```
package mypackage;

public class myClass {

    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;

    public myClass(int a, int b, int c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

I then create an arraylist in another class file:

```
ArrayList<myClass > myArrayList= new ArrayList<myClass>();
```

But how do I add data to it?  I want to do something like this:

```
for(int indexer = 0; indexer < count; indexer++){
    myArrayList[indexer].a = 5;
    myArrayList[indexer].b = 5;
    myArrayList[indexer].c = 5;
}
```

This obviously doesn't work.  How is this suppose to work?

Comment: ArrayList has add() method. To get the item, use get() method

Answer (score 3):

Look, your `myArrayList` is an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of `myClass`. So to add elements into `myArrayList` you need `myCLass` objects. (Offtopic: Please use capital letter for class naming, say `MyClass` instead of `myClass`). For example,

```
myClass myClassObject = new myClass(5, 5, 5);
```

Now use [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) to add `myClassObject` object into your ArrayList

```
myArrayList.add(myClassObject);
```

Comment: I knew it couldn't be too complicated!

Comment: yeah, it isn't!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access `a,b,c` variables you got to declare them like this

`public static int a;
public static int b;` and so on. Another option is to create `getters and setters:`

```
private int a;

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a=a;
}
```

Otherwise, use the `List` add method `myArrayList.add(...);`